# How does Mann Up mode affect item drop rate?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

Since [the Mann Up mode alters the item drop rate](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80859/what-is-mann-up-mode) somehow, I'd like to know how the "regular" Mann versus Machine's [drop system](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) works. 
Is it working like for any other map or mode?  Or is the drop rate reduced, for instance?

From my personal experience, so far I dropped two random items at a rate that seems pretty much normal to me.

Comment: My personal experience is same as yours (only I've got three items so far ^.^ ), seems the same to me.

Comment: I don't think there is any change in item drop rate with Mann Up. The key (only?) difference is just that you get items at the end of a Mann Up round, in exchange for the ticket/voucher you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official wiki [contains no mention](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system) of altered drop rates in Mann Up, or any other mode. The current item drop system uses time to determine when to drop an item at regular intervals between 30 and 70 minutes (50 minutes on average), generally after you die.

[image]